# Is Camel Automatically generate SOAP Message?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel

Is Apache Camel automatically generate SOAP Message if we provide required object structure?

If not than why should I use Camel for calling web service?

Please provide me specific reason which help it out for calling any SOAP Web Service.

My Camel Configuration is

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .process(new Processor() {

                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                System.out.println("In ........");
                                exchange.getIn().setBody("<country>india</country>");
                                System.out.println("in process method");
                                System.out.println(exchange.getExchangeId() + " : " + exchange.getFromRouteId() + " : " + exchange.isFailed());
                            }
                        }).
                        to("cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?" + "wsdlURL=http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?wsdl&"
                                + "serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET}airport&" + "portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET}airportSoap&"
                                + "defaultOperationName=GetAirportInformationByCountry&" + "dataFormat=MESSAGE")
                        .to("file:/home/viral?fileName=output.txt");

            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you share your camel configuration ?

Comment: From the 3 offered method Camel/CXF provide (`Message`, `Payload`, `Pojo`) I guess Pojo is what you are after. Have you already read the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) therefore? Next, who forces you to use Camel in first place? For simply sending and receiving SOAP messages you could also use CXF or any other SOAP framework as well - most of them provide some kind of POJO<-->SOAP ability (often based on JAXB)

Comment: I have search example for Pojo but i am not able to find it out. please provide me sample code for same. as i am new in camel. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Apache Camel automatically generate SOAP Message if we provide required object structure?

overall YES,

You don't need to make SOAP envelop by your own. You just need to write your custom `Processor` in which you define SOAP message. Plus in `camelContext` you need to define your `endpoint` and `route`. It will also handle `soapfault` in case of error or you can write your own custom error SOAP responses all well.

**Update in reply of you comment :**

if you want to make your generic camel processor then you can add your message body in XML file every time and set to SOAPBody like this

```
...
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("In ........");

  try {
    File file = new File("soapbody.xml"); // generic body in separate XML file for every time 
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    String body = doc.toString();
    exchange.getIn().setBody(body );

  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("in process method");
  System.out.println(exchange.getExchangeId() + " : " + exchange.getFromRouteId() + " : " + exchange.isFailed());
}
...
```

Comment: any how we need to write some logic in processor right?

Comment: yes that's obvious, it depends on your business requirement

Comment: Actually i need to developed generic utility which accept input for web service in form of object, now i need to create message to soap. how i am able to create soap in processor in generic way so that i am able to call any type of web service using camel. as per your request i have added camel config in question itself. i need to pass country in web service. please suggest me what should i do so that i am able to call any kind of SOAP based web service

Comment: if you want processor in generic way then you can put you message body i XML file and read XML file and set in message body. see my update in answer

Comment: Actually requirement is i need to create integration framework which take objects as a input and call web service. that's it. no XML i have. so whats the proposed solution from your side.